# What happened on freeaddrinfo called?

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I'm learning network programming by following the [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#simpleserver) article. There is an example:

```
struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;

if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
    return 1;
}

// loop through all the results and bind to the first we can
for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
    //socket(...)
    //bind(...)
    break;
}

freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this structure

if (p == NULL)  {
    fprintf(stderr, "server: failed to bind\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

After `bind()`, `freeaddrinfo()` is called. I think the `servinfo` link list should be NULL now, and also the pointer `p` should be NULL, but no, `p` is not NULL and the code works well.

I want to know why the `p` is not null after calling `freeaddrinfo` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the loop the pointer `p` either points to the `addrinfo` structure that was used to successfully create and bind the socket, or it will be `NULL` if none of the structures could be used.

That the `freeaddrinfo` was called between the loop and the check doesn't matter, because you don't dereference the variable `p`, you only check if it's a null-pointer or not.

However, if you try to dereference `p` after the call to `freeaddrinfo` then you would try to access memory no longer allocated to you, and you will have *undefined behavior*.

The `freeaddrinfo` call doesn't change any of your variables, it can't. If you have a pointer allocated with `malloc` and then you call `free` with that variable, it doesn't set the variable to `NULL`, nor could it set any other variable pointing to the same memory to `NULL`. Read more about *passing argument by value* and *emulating pass by reference in c* to learn more about why.

Comment: Yes!Yes!! The pointer is remain the pointer. Even the `*p` is null. Thank you!

Comment: `*p` is not guaranteed to be NULL after `freeaddrinfo()` is called. If `*p` is getting NULL'ed then that is a side effect of the memory manager that allocated and is freeing `serveinfo`. Some memory managers *do* zero out memory when freeing it (or even fill it with special values like `0xcdcdcdcd` or `0xbaadfood` to aid debugging), but you can't rely on that behavior in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It's no different than what happens when you use free - the pointer still points to the same address yet the actual memory is not allocated. The reason this isn't a simple free call is that you're actually free'ing a list of resources. From the manual:

> The freeaddrinfo() function frees the memory that was allocated for
>   the dynamically allocated linked list res.